# Disable default Android browser

Tags: android

Is there a basic example showing how to disable the default Android browser on a Samsung Galaxy S6, MDM or otherwise, without root permissions? I’ve already tried the basic profile example; however, it does not encompass what I need.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to

> settings>apps>(all tab)>Browser>Click "Disable"

you won't have to ever answer if you want a link or anything to open in Browser or  Chrome. It will act like Browser isn't on your phone and default to Chrome.

Comment: Thanks. Many browsers / apps cannot be disabled as the “Disable” button is greyed out. MDM software can do it; however, I’m looking to do it programmatically.